# How to find the maximum likelihood estimators for this small data set?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Source of the question: the Exercise 7.2(b) of Statistical Inference Book by Casella and Berger.

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a gamma($\alpha,\beta$) population.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both unknown, there is no explicit formula for the MLEs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but the maximum can be found numerically.  Find the MLEs for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the below data.

First, I know how to find the MLE of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The rule is the sample average is the MLE of $\alpha \beta$. For each fixed value of $\alpha$, the value of  $\beta$ that maximizes L is $\Sigma_i x_i/ (n \alpha)$. Substitute this into L. Then we just need to maximize the function of the one variable $\alpha$ given by

$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)^n   (\Sigma_i x_i/ (n \alpha))^{n \alpha} }  [\prod_{i=1}^n x_i]^{\alpha-1} e^{-n\alpha}$

The data is:

22.0, 23.9, 20.9, 23.8, 25.0, 24.0, 21.7, 23.8, 22.8, 23.1, 23.1, 23.5, 23.0, 23.0

My attempt:

```
data <- c(22.0,23.9,20.9,23.8,25.0,24.0,21.7,23.8,22.8,23.1,23.1,23.5,23.0,23.0)

mean(data)

f = function(x){
  1/ ((gamma(x))^14 * (23.11429/x)^(14*x)) * prod(data)^(x-1) * exp(-14*x)
}

ans = optimize(f, interval = c(0,1000), maximum = TRUE)

# extract the coordinates of the maximum
x_max = ans$maximum
y_max = ans$objective
```

But my code gives me a wrong answer. I don't know where I got wrong. But mean(data) is correct.

Comment: Typically, one looks at the derivatives of the log likelihood function, here wrt $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and then calculation where these equal 0. The solution to this is eg given in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution. Maybe try if this works better for you. Note that at Wikipedia an approximate value exists which doesn’t require using Newtons method, it might be good to compare with.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to rather consider the log likelihood, which tends to simplify things. I urge you to read about likelihood estimation atleast to some degree to understand why this is customary. In this case is given by

$$
\ln(\mathcal{L(k,\theta}) = (k-1)\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x_i}{\theta}-Nk\ln(\theta)-N\ln(\Gamma(k))
$$

as stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). Solving for $\frac{d}{dk}\ln(\mathcal{L(k,\theta})=0$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln(\mathcal{L(k,\theta})=0$ gives

$$
\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{kN}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i
$$

and

$$
\ln(\hat{k})-\psi(\hat{k})=\ln\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i \right) - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(x_i)
$$

where the latter is solved numerically and $\psi(k)$ is the digamma function. If you plug in the numbers, you should get $\hat{k}\approx23.1$ and $\hat{\theta}\approx0.04$.

Comment: Can I see your R codes?

Comment: I do not use R. I do however think you should try to implement it yourself.